# why in this situation the showgroup function prints a window object instead of a group object?

Tags: javascript, oop

```js
let group = {
  title: "Our Group",
  showgroup: function() {
    var test = function() {
      console.log(this)
    }
    test();
  },
};

group.showgroup()
```

Comment: You didn't create an instance here, just an object literal. For oop, use either of there: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/6ocatj0v/

Comment: Because the call that's responsible for determining the `this` context is `test();`, not `group.showgroup()`